# Does the Selenium Chrome remote webdriver with mobile emulation support touch gestures?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

Does the Selenium Chrome remote webdriver support mobile emulation with touch actions or gestures? I got the following exception when running touch actions on a Selenium grid.

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
 Underlying driver does not implement advanced user interactions yet.
```

Obviously the exception says no, but I want to know if this is not because of a implementation mistake I made.

I basically have the following code:

```
RemoteTouchScreen touch = new RemoteTouchScreen(WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver);

touch.Down(startX, startY); //exception thrown
touch.Up(endX, startY);
```

if the `WebDriver` is of type `ChromeDriver`, which runs locally it works perfectly. If I use the `RemoteWebDriver` class it fails with the mentioned exception.

Both the drivers have mobile emulation enabled which I can see working in both situations.

- Used .Net Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings
- Used Selenium server: selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

Comment: Does it work with a remote node launched on your station? Is the returned capability `hasTouchScreen` set to `true` ?

Comment: @FlorentB. Don't have the a remote node locally, need to set that up. Yes capability `hasTouchScreen` is set to true.

Comment: @FlorentB. same error when running a grid on my station.

Comment: It's an issue with the standalone server. It seems that the Java client is failing to implement the touch screen feature which is supported by the Chrome driver. You should report the issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues

Comment: @FlorentB. Ok. Will do that in the weekends. Thanks for taking the time.